# Storing the path of a file in a listbox

Tags: vba

I am making a music player application. I am using a ListBox to display the songs. When the user adds a song, it displays the full path of the song. But I want it to only display the song name(The songs can be located in any folder in any drive). A windows media player control is playing the songs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to say which presentation framework you're using here Sadia. It sounds like it might be WPF/Silverlight but it could be Winforms or something else.  Also you need to paste in some code for people to help more easily.

Answer (score 0):

So You want to extract only the song name from the whole path of the song. A simple tricky logic will do these. This is VBA

```
sub song_name_extractor()
    song_path = "c:\songs\favret\mylove.mp3" ' Assume this is where the song is
    song_name = Right(song_path, Len(song_path) - InStrRev(song_path, "\"))
    Msgbox song_name  'outputs mylove.mp3 
    song_name = Left(song_name, InStrRev(song_name, ".") - 1)
    Msgbox song_name ' outputs only mylove removes extensions of file
end sub
```

Explaination:

```
Right Func, cuts the right part of the string into sub-string of given number
Len Func, To find the length of the string
InStrRev Fun, gives the point of occurrence, of the given character in a string
searching from right to left 
Left Func, cuts the Left part of the string into sub-string of given number
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this:
1. Create an object that can hold the info of the song.
2. Create an list that holds all songs in the playlist.
3. Add that list as a datasource to the listbox, By setting .DisplayMember, you are telling wich property will be visible as listitemtext in the listbox.
4. When listindex changes, get the object stored in listbox.SelectedItem and ctype it to an songobject to work with it.

```
Public Class Form1

Structure SongObject
    Public SongPath As String
    Public NameNoExtension As String
    Public SongLength As Integer
    Public SongRating As Integer
    Private _FileName
    Public Property FileName() As String
        Get
            Return _filename
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _FileName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal path As String)
        SongPath = path
        FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
        NameNoExtension = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
        SongLength = 0 'fix
        SongRating = 5 'fix
    End Sub

End Structure

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim musicpath As String = "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\"

    'Load songs into listbox
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName"
    Dim songs As New List(Of SongObject)
    For Each f As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(musicpath, "*.mp3")
         songs.Add(New SongObject(f))
    Next
    ListBox1.DataSource = songs
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Get songitem
    Dim SelectedSong As SongObject = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, SongObject)
    MsgBox("Path:" & SelectedSong.SongPath & vbCrLf & "FileName:" & SelectedSong.FileName)
    'Todo: play selected song...
End Sub
End Class
```

Use IO.Path.GetFileName(path)  and IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) to get filename instead of right/left/instr/mid and so on.